# Perl Script to determine how many logins were still on the system after 16:00

Tags: perl

I have a data file that displays the following data:

```
cfs264su pts/6        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 16:46 - 19:21  (02:34)
cfs264su pts/6        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 16:30 - 16:46  (00:15)
cfs264su pts/6        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 16:19 - 16:30  (00:10)
cfs264su pts/6        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 14:59 - 15:30  (00:31)
cfs264su pts/5        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 14:40 - 17:13  (02:33)
cfs264su pts/1        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 14:02 - 19:06  (05:03)
cfs264su pts/6        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 10:36 - 13:18  (02:41)
cfs264su pts/5        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 10:22 - 12:45  (02:23)
cfs264su pts/1        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 08:45 - 12:12  (03:27)
cfs264su pts/5        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 00:34 - 01:28  (00:54)
```

I have created a perl script that is suppose to display how many logins were still signed in after 16:00 on May 26th. This is what I have so far and cant figure out how to display the correct number of logins which are 5.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open(FILE, $ARGV[0]) or die ("Error Found: $!");
while ( $line = <FILE> ) {
 ($login, $time) = split('\(', $line);
#  print "Time: $time";
 ($hour,$m) = split('\:',$time);
#  print "Hour: $hour\n";
 if ( $hour <= 16 ) {
#    print "Found: $hour\n";
    $n++;
 }
}

print "There were $n logins that were still on the system after 16:00 on May 26.\n";
close(FILE);
```

Comment: *after* should be 3, no? And the time is the hh:mm just after 'May 26'... In the ()'s that's the duration.

Comment: That is a bad way to use `split`. Also, not using `use strict; use warnings` is a bad idea.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm very new to perl script and this is a homework question that I'm struggling with. I'm at a complete loss at this point.

Comment: Your logic here is that the "time logged in" should be over 16 if they are still logged in after 16:00. This is not true. There is no one with over 16 hours. You have to check the logout time.

Comment: What can you tell us of the input? Is it fixed width or tab-separated? If it is the latter, you can use split to separate the columns. If the former, you can use unpack, or substr.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figure it out. the split had to use / - /

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open(FILE, $ARGV[0]) or die ("Error Found: $!");
while ( $line = <FILE> ) {
 ($login, $time) = split(/ - /, $line);
#  print "Time: $time";
 ($hour,$m) = split('/ - /:',$time);
#  print "Hour: $hour\n";
 if ( $hour < 16 ) {
#    print "Found: $hour\n";
    $n++;
 }
}

print "There were $n logins that were still on the system after 16:00 on May 26.\n";
close(FILE);
```

Thanks!

Comment: No... `split ('/ - /:', $time)` is very incorrect. You do not have that in your input, so that line does nothing.. It works because the logout time is first in `$time`, so the `<` operation will try to cast for example `14:40 - 17:13  (02:33)` into a number, and ending up with `14`, which works for you. I believe I also told you to add `use strict; use warnings` to your code to avoid making simple mistakes. Learning Perl without those is like trying to learn it while blindfolded.

Answer (score 0):

Following code sample demonstrates one of possible ways.

Algorithm:

- convert *date and time* into epoch for `$start` and `$end` timeframe
- read input data into hash `$record->{@fields}` with fields as keys
- store read record into HoA `%login` with *userid* as a key
- for user of interest go through all records
- compare *login time* with `$start` and `$end` timeframe
- if match increase `$count`
- print `$count` on completion

Run as:

- Linux   `script.pl user '[start]' '[end]'`
- Windows `script.pl user "[start]" "[end]"`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Date::Parse;

my $user  = shift || 'cfs264su';
my $start = shift || 'May 26 10:00 2020';
my $end   = shift || 'May 26 15:00 2020';

$start = date2epoch($start);
$end   = date2epoch($end);

say 'USER:  ' . $user;
say 'START: ' . scalar localtime $start;
say 'END:   ' . scalar localtime $end;
say '-' x 45;

my %login;
my @fields = qw/id pts what wday month mday in out duration/;
my $count;

while( <DATA> ) {
    my($id, $record);
    $record->@{@fields} = split "[- ()]+";
    $id = $record->{id};
    delete $record->{id};
    push @{$login{$id}}, $record;
}


for( @{$login{$user}} ) {
    my $in  = date2epoch(join ' ', $_->@{qw/month mday in/});
    my $out = date2epoch(join ' ', $_->@{qw/month mday out/});

    if( $in >= $start && $in <= $end) {
        ++$count;
        say 'IN:    ' . scalar localtime $in;
        say 'OUT:   ' . scalar localtime $out;
        say '-' x 45;
    }
}

say "Logged in: $count times";

exit;

sub date2epoch {
    my $date = shift;
    
    return str2time($date);
}

__DATA__
cfs264su pts/6        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 16:46 - 19:21  (02:34)
cfs264su pts/6        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 16:30 - 16:46  (00:15)
cfs264su pts/6        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 16:19 - 16:30  (00:10)
cfs264su pts/6        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 14:59 - 15:30  (00:31)
cfs264su pts/5        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 14:40 - 17:13  (02:33)
cfs264su pts/1        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 14:02 - 19:06  (05:03)
cfs264su pts/6        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 10:36 - 13:18  (02:41)
cfs264su pts/5        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 10:22 - 12:45  (02:23)
cfs264su pts/1        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 08:45 - 12:12  (03:27)
cfs264su pts/5        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 00:34 - 01:28  (00:54)
```

Output

```
USER:  cfs264su
START: Tue May 26 10:00:00 2020
END:   Tue May 26 15:00:00 2020
---------------------------------------------
IN:    Tue May 26 14:59:00 2020
OUT:   Tue May 26 15:30:00 2020
---------------------------------------------
IN:    Tue May 26 14:40:00 2020
OUT:   Tue May 26 17:13:00 2020
---------------------------------------------
IN:    Tue May 26 14:02:00 2020
OUT:   Tue May 26 19:06:00 2020
---------------------------------------------
IN:    Tue May 26 10:36:00 2020
OUT:   Tue May 26 13:18:00 2020
---------------------------------------------
IN:    Tue May 26 10:22:00 2020
OUT:   Tue May 26 12:45:00 2020
---------------------------------------------
Logged in: 5 times
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach using [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Time::Piece;

# The format of the dates and times that we're dealing with
my $fmt = '%b %d %H:%M';
# Store the count
my $count;

# Get a Time::Piece object that represents our cut-off time    
my $cutoff = Time::Piece->strptime('May 26 16:00', $fmt);

# Note: I'm reading from DATA here. It's an easy way to
# prototype stuff without having to deal with opening files
while (<DATA>) {
  # Split the data on whitespace
  # Pull out columns 4, 5 and 8
  # Join them with a space - which gives us the end date/time
  my $end_str = join ' ', (split /\s+/)[4, 5, 8];

  # Parse that string into a Time::Piece object
  my $end = Time::Piece->strptime($end_str, $fmt);

  # Increment the counter if this date/time is
  # greater than the cut-off
  $count++ if $end > $cutoff;
}

say $count;

__DATA__
cfs264su pts/6        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 16:46 - 19:21  (02:34)
cfs264su pts/6        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 16:30 - 16:46  (00:15)
cfs264su pts/6        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 16:19 - 16:30  (00:10)
cfs264su pts/6        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 14:59 - 15:30  (00:31)
cfs264su pts/5        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 14:40 - 17:13  (02:33)
cfs264su pts/1        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 14:02 - 19:06  (05:03)
cfs264su pts/6        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 10:36 - 13:18  (02:41)
cfs264su pts/5        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 10:22 - 12:45  (02:23)
cfs264su pts/1        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 08:45 - 12:12  (03:27)
cfs264su pts/5        x.x.x.x.x        Tue May 26 00:34 - 01:28  (00:54)
```